# How to multiply data to get value | Oracle |

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 table **Table 1 : Employee** and **Table 2 : Department**

**Below is the join condition i have used**

```
select e.empsal,d.rate from employee e left join on department d where  e.empid = d.depid
```

Based on `d.rate` the value of `e.empsal` should get multiple , upto join condition i was able to do after that where to add case is not getting , if you see `drate` value will be anything
if their are 25 drate values like : `1  2 4 6 7 9 14 36 67 8 2 4 19 11 8`
It is not feasible to write that many times if conditions

```
case drate 
if 0 then e.empsal*1
if 1 then e.empsal*10
if 2 then e.empsal*100
if 4 then e.empsal*1000
if 6 then e.empsal*1000000
...
```

**Example : Below is the logic and its Output expected:**

```
if d.rate value is 0 then  new_empsal=e.empsal * 1
if d.rate value is 1 then  new_empsal=e.empsal * 10
if d.rate value is 2 then  new_empsal=e.empsal * 100
if d.rate value is 3 then  new_empsal=e.empsal * 1000
will go on ...
```

**So the new values of** `e.empsal` **should be below**

```
EMPSAL,DRATE,NEW_EMPSAL
1200,0,1200
2345,1,23450
1678,3,1678000
2219,6,2219000000
2458,1,24580
2697,2,269700
2936,1,29360
3175,4,31750000
3414,7,34140000000
3653,2,365300
3892,1,38920
4131,1,41310
4566,0,4566
4131,4,41310000
1000,6,1000000000
345,1,3450
2345,5,234500000
1123,0,1123
990,3,990000
1100,3,1100000
345,7,3450000000
2345,2,234500
```

***How to achieve this below output using above condition ?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a `case` expression?

```
select e.*,
       (case d.rate
           when 0 then 1 when 1 then 10 when 2 then 100 when 3 then 1000 when 4 then 10000 when 6 then 1000000
        end) * e.empsal
from employee e left join
     department d
     on e.depid = d.depid;
```

Note that this fixes your syntax using `where` instead of `on`.  I also changed the `join` condition, because matching `empid` to `depid` doesn't make much sense to me.

Or more concisely using [`power()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/POWER.html#GUID-D280B322-D2C3-46D0-8076-C88F16CBEDC2):

```
select e.*, power(10, d.rate) * e.empsal
from employee e left join
     department d
     on e.dep = d.depid;
```